# Nested pie chart in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I'm trying to achieve the following o/p from bokeh which is deprecated now. In the new structure, I need to layer everything like working in HTML. Is there any simplified example like this [bokeh pie chart(deprecated)](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.5/docs/gallery/donut_chart.html) ?[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of a single "combined" example but there is a basic Pie chart example here (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/pie/pie.html) and a Donut chart example here (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/pie/donut.html) so you would more or less just combine those two examples to get a chart like the one above.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks for the reply. I thought about that. But it's not an easy one like before. That's why I tried here.

Comment: Well, the "easy on from before" was part of `bokeh.charts` which was barely functional and did not have a maintainer, so it had to be jettisoned from the main library. If you want to simplify things, it's probably possible to use `annular_wedge` with `inner_radius=0` for the inner wedges, so  that all levels can be created consistently. There might be higher level tools (e.g. holoviews or pandas-bokeh) that offer a multi-level pie chart, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`wegde`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.wedge) and [`annular_wedge`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.annular_wedge)

The example code below creates this figure:

[image: medal cake]

### Example code

##### Pandas

Lets say we have this data table for the medals of a sport event.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['Fra', 'Deu', 'Can', 'USA'],
    'Gold': [0,1,2,3],
    'Silver': [1,2,2,2],
    'Bronze':[3,2,1,3]
})
>>> df
  Country  Gold  Silver  Bronze
0     FRA     0       1       3
1     GER     1       2       2
2     CAN     2       2       1
3     USA     3       2       3
```

Now we have to calculate the angles to use the bokeh wedges. We use a copy to not overwrite the original data.

```
# get a copy and calculate the angles
_df = df.copy()
_df['Country_total'] = _df[['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']].sum(axis=1)
total_sum = _df['Country_total'].sum()
_df["End"] = _df['Country_total'].div(total_sum).mul(2 * np.pi).cumsum().round(6)
_df["Start"] = _df["End"].shift(1).fillna(0)
_df['Color'] = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'magenta']
_df
```

##### Bokeh

Here we loop over all rows of the DataFrame and draw the annular wedge first and then the inner wedge to get the correct color in the legend.

```
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=400, height=300, match_aspect=True, x_range=(-2.2,2.2), y_range=(-2.2,2.2))

p.add_layout(
    Legend(
        click_policy="hide",
        margin=1,
    ),
    "right",
)

p.rect(x=0, y=0, width=2, height=2, alpha=0)

wedges = []
for i, item in _df.iterrows():
    start = item["Start"]
    end = item["End"]

    start_angle = start
    end_angle = start
    for value, color in zip(['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'], ['gold', 'silver', '#bf8970']):
        angle = np.round(item[value] / total_sum * 2 * np.pi, 6)
        end_angle += angle
        p.annular_wedge(
            x=0,
            y=0,
            inner_radius=1,
            outer_radius=2,
            start_angle=start_angle,
            end_angle=end_angle,
            color=color,
            line_color='white',
            legend_label=item['Country'],
        )
        start_angle += angle

    p.wedge(
        x=0,
        y=0,
        radius=1,
        start_angle=start,
        end_angle=end,
        color=item["Color"],
        line_color='white',
        legend_label=item['Country'],
    )
p.xgrid.visible = False
p.ygrid.visible = False

show(p)
```

### Comment

I hope this is close tou your wanted solution.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm expecting something similar to the previous one. As I said earlier,  Here we're doing everything like a designer. Instead, if we have a codebase like the previous one, it'll be easy to use.